# How do I display file names in an encoding other than UTF-8?

Tags: finder, internationalization

I have a couple of files/directories that are named in GBK. I think because finder assumes UTF-8 encoding, all of those file names are displayed as gibberish. How do I make Finder display their file names properly?

Answer (score 2):

- You need to move `Chinese` language to the top of the `Preferred languages` list in `System Preferences` > `Language & Region`:

  [image: Preferred languages]
- If you have Chinese file and folder names created in OS 9 and earlier, you can use [File Name Encoding Repair Utility](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL355?locale=en_US) (untested).
- This [script gist](https://gist.github.com/henices/10243394) also renames filename in GBK to UTF-8 (untested).
- I found interesting information for using the Chinese language on the Mac [here](http://chinesemac.org/index.html).
- I also recommend you to read [OS X: Cross-platform filename best practices and conventions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202808).
- In [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/chinesemac/kZAEkyOrnPI/jwiMx1FdJ2kJ) forum there are user experiments about this problem.